# ListView isn't using custom ListItemComponent

Tags: listview, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I'm trying to use a custom *ListItemComponent* in my cascades however it is ignoring it. Instead of drawing my *Label*, coloring it cyan and putting ListItemData.text in, it fills my list with ListItemData.description (my json has text, description, status and image). [You can see screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbniQ.png). If i use *StandardListItem* all information is displayed properly.

**QML:**

```qml
Page {
    Container {
        ListView {
            id: myListView
            dataModel: MyListModel {
                id: myListModel
            }
            listItemComponents: [
                ListItemComponent {
                    type: "listItem"

                    Container {
                        id:item
                        layout: StackLayout {
                            orientation: LayoutOrientation.LeftToRight
                        }
                        Label {
                            id: text
                            text: ListItemData.text
                            textStyle {
                                color: Color.Cyan
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
    onCreationCompleted: {
        myListModel.load("app/native/assets/mydata.json")
    }
}
```

**c++:**

```cpp
void MyListModel::load(const QString& file_name)
{
    bb::data::JsonDataAccess jda;
    QVariantList lst = jda.load(file_name).value<QVariantList>();
    if (jda.hasError()) {
        bb::data::DataAccessError error = jda.error();
        qDebug() << file_name << "JSON loading error: " << error.errorType() << ": " << error.errorMessage();
    }
    else {
        qDebug() << file_name << "JSON data loaded OK!";
        append(lst);
    }
}

QVariant MyListModel::value(int ix, const QString &fld_name)
{
    QVariant ret;
    if(ix >= 0 && ix < size()) {
        QVariantMap curr_val = QVariantListDataModel::value(ix).toMap();
        ret = curr_val.value(fld_name);
    }
    return ret;
}

void MyListModel::setValue(int ix, const QString& fld_name, const QVariant& val)
{      
    if(ix >= 0 && ix < size()) { 
        QVariantMap curr_val = QVariantListDataModel::value(ix).value<QVariantMap>();
        curr_val[fld_name] = val;
        replace(ix, curr_val);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can someone add "ListItemComponent" to tags please, I don't have enough rep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on the type your DataModel implements/inherits from. When a ListView needs to know the type of an item for display, in most cases (see [ListItemTypeMapper](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__listitemtypemapper.html) for the exception) it calls `itemType()` from the [DataModel](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__datamodel.html).  By default most datamodels will return an empty string, but a [GroupDataModel](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__groupdatamodel.html#function-itemtype-indexpath) will return either "header" or "item" depending on whether the item is a header or not.

You have specified that your `ListItemComponent` is only valid for items of type "listItem", which most probably does not match what your `MyListModel::itemType()` is returning. If `MyListModel` is a `GroupDataModel`, then change your `ListItemComponent` to be for `type: "item"`, otherwise use `type: ""` or remove the `type` property altogether so that your `ListItemComponent` is used by default for all items.

Answer (score 0):

In the ListItemComponent{  }, you have a "type:" field, you should set the value as "item", ie. **type:"item"**. Then  the list view will use custom component